# Movie about a man trapped in a tree by muggers

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a movie at least ten years ago. It was a made-for-tv movie about a man who was walking through a park, when he was mugged. He sought refuge in a tree.

The "trapped in a tree" device made the movie a bit ridiculous, but the suspense was well-managed and the Hitchcockian every-man-facing-extraordinary-situation aspect sold it for me.

I think it was a TV movie, made in Canada. I have a feeling like it was set in Toronto. Does anyone remember this film?

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Treed Murray (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0293664/)

> Dressed in his business attire and carrying an expensive briefcase, a marketing executive named Murray is taking a shortcut through an urban park in Toronto. Lost in a secluded area of the park, he gets into an altercation with a teen-aged punk, who unknown to Murray is only one of five - four guys and a girl - in a gang. Running to get away from the gang, Murray has the idea that he will climb up a large tree to hide out until the punks leave. Unfortunately for Murray, they find him in the tree. Initially, Murray believes he has no other alternative but to do what they say. But Murray and the punks soon realize that Murray has some leverage being where he is. This altercation soon becomes a standoff and a test of wills to see who can outlast the other, the standoff which includes both physical and emotional torment on both sides, the latter as each learns more about the other.